# How to compare dates in computed columns?

Tags: sql-server, date, calculated-columns

DateColumn is of type `date`. I want to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyComputedColumn AS (DateColumn < '2010-12-31');
```

I have also tried:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyComputedColumn AS (DateColumn < convert(date, '2010-12-31'));
```

But there are syntax errors. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Can you include the error?

Comment: Did you really want a computed column or did you perhaps mean it to be a [check constraint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't have a data type to directly represent 'true' and 'false.  You have to use a case statement and return a primitive type.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyComputedColumn AS (CASE WHEN (DateColumn < '2010-12-31') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want this to be a bit field:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyComputedColumn AS (ISNULL(CONVERT(bit,case when (DateColumn < '2010-12-31') 
then 0 
else 1 
end),0))
```